# Is it due to different C compiler?

Tags: c

I'm studying some programs, the programs are basically **to illustrate some common C problem**. I get the video tutorial from youtube, I've checked many times, the codes that I wrote look exactly the same as the tutor's codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int SumOfElements(int A[])
{
  int i;
  int sum;
  sum = 0;
  int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]); 

  for(i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    sum+= A[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

int main() {
  int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

  int total = SumOfElements(A);
  printf("Sum of elements = %d\n",total);
}
```

When I compiled the program, I get this error:

```
pointer.c: In function ‘SumOfElements’:
pointer.c:9:21: warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘A’ will
return size of ‘int *’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
                 ^
pointer.c:4:23: note: declared here
int SumOfElements(int A[])
```

The tutor's OS is windows, while mine is linux using gcc compiler. When the tutor ran the program, he got:

```
Sum of Elements = 1
```

My question: Could this be due to different C compiler that we both used?

Comment: The code is wrong. The tutor is probably not qualified to be tutoring anybody.

Comment: Your output is not from running the program, it's from compiling it. Did you actually run it?

Comment: Read warning messages.

Comment: @EOF, BLUEPIXY That wasn't the question.

Comment: @melpomene: But it *is* the answer.

Comment: @EOF Not if the tutor is demonstrating a silently misbehaving program due to a coding bug. Note that the expected output is "*Sum of Elements = 1*". OP seems to be wondering why they're not getting any "sum" at all.

Comment: @melpomene: If the tutor explained why the code is wrong, the OP should *really* have **absolutely** no trouble at all understanding the compiler warning.

Comment: @EOF I believe OP is confused about compiling vs running a program. Note that OP also thinks the warnings are errors.

Comment: Link to the tutorial would help...

Comment: here is the tutorial link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpjVucvAc3g

Comment: @LionGordon How about my question? Did you actually run the program? What commands did you enter, exactly?

Comment: @melpomene ofcourse I ran it, otherwise how could i get that error

Comment: @LionGordon As I told you before, that "error" is not from running the program. It's compiler output, from compiling the program.

Comment: @melpomene oh yeah sorry, you're right, I should've said the error generated during compilation

Comment: @LionGordon So now you're comparing apples and oranges: "When the tutor *ran* the program, he got X. When I *compiled* the program, I got Y." What exactly is your question, then? (Also, that compiler output is just a warning, not an error. It'll still produce an executable.)

Comment: @melpomene my question is actually : Why can the tutor compile and run the program with no problem?, but I can't even compile the program succesfully with the same codes.

Comment: @LionGordon Why do you think you can't compile it? A compiler warning doesn't mean it didn't work.

Comment: @melpomene but why didn't the tutor have compiler warning?

Comment: Why do you think the tutor didn't have a compiler warning? The video doesn't show the compilation process.

Comment: @JJJ this assumption could probably be true.

Comment: @LionGordon Compilers are free to warn for anything they want. The Visual Studio and GCC compiler probably have not a single common (verbatim) warning message. To answer your question why one compiler issues a message and the other does not: because messages are only required for **violations of syntax** and (what the C Standard calls) **constraints**.

Comment: @EOF You got this completely wrong. This program is **intended** to show the problem of sizeof on pointers. The OP explicitly says so.

Comment: @Jens: It does so after *your edit* all right. Before, it was not explicit in any way.

Comment: @EOF I **emphasized** the wording so people wouldn't jump on the obvious "error" in the program. The OPs problem in understanding is with respect to something different: why are there compiler warnings for him, when in the video there are none (visible).

Comment: @Jens it starts to make sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well .... yes, the different results are due to different compilers, but that's only an effect, not the cause of what you are observing.

Actually, both your compiler and the tutor's compiler are correct according to the C standard.

In `SumOfElements()`, `A` is a pointer to an `int`  (i.e. an `int *`) not an array.

Within `main()`, the call `SumOfElements(A)` implicitly converts `A` (the name of an array of 4 `int`) into a pointer equal to `&A[0]`, and that is the value received within the body of `SumOfElements()`.   This is known as the "array to pointer conversion" and is a fundamental feature of C (it has existed in all C standards, and actually existed in every version of C, even before a standard was produced).

As a result, within `SumOfElements()`, `sizeof(A)` is equal to the size of an `int *` - which your compiler is warning you about.   `sizeof(A[0])`, since `A[0]` is of type `int`, is equal to `sizeof(int)`.

The catch is that the results of `sizeof` is implementation defined for most types (other than `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` which all have size `1` by definition in the C standard).   This means `sizeof (int *)` and `sizeof (int)` both depend on the compiler.

With your tutor's compiler,  it happens that `sizeof (int *) == sizeof(int)`, hence the value of `1` being returned by `SumOfElements()`.

With your compiler (unless you have configured it to treat warnings as errors) you will be able to successfully build the code.    You may or may not get the value of `1` being returned by `SumOfElements()` though.

Don't worry about the fact that your tutor's compiler gives no warning, and yours does.   Compilers are generally not REQUIRED to issue warnings - and, in fact, most compilers are configured by default to give a minimal number of warnings.   The code is valid, albeit it has results that vary between compilers.

**Note 1:**   The discussion would probably be a little clearer if, in `main()` the array was given a name other than `A`, so it doesn't have the same name as the declared argument for `SumOfElements()`.   The `A` in `main()` is actually a different thing completely from the `A` in `SumOfElements()`, even though both are named `A`.

Answer (score -1):

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type **‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’** that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.

and (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 7 A declaration of a parameter as **‘‘array of type’’ shall be
>   adjusted to ‘‘qualiﬁed pointer to type’’**, where the type qualiﬁers
>   (if any) are those speciﬁed within the [ and ] of the array type
>   derivation...

Thus this function declaration

```
int SumOfElements(int A[]);
```

is equivalent to the function declaration

```
int SumOfElements( int *A);
```

As result within the function this statement

```
int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
```

is equivalent to

```
int size = sizeof( int *)/sizeof(int);
```

and yields either 2 or 1 depending on the sizes of the types `int *` and `int`. Or the compiler can issue a diagnostic message depending on the compiler implementation and used compiler options

Take into account that the type of the value returned by the operator `sizeof` is `size_t`.

You should explicitly pass the size of the array to the function. For example

```
long long int SumOfElements( int A[], size_t size )
{
    size_t i;
    long long int sum;

    sum = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
       sum += A[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

and call the function like

```
long long int total = SumOfElements( A, sizeof( A ) / sizeof( A[0] ) );
printf( "Sum of elements = %lld\n", total );
```

Comment: That's not an answer. The expected output is `Sum of Elements = 1`. You're explaining why the expected output is expected, not why OP is getting what he's actually getting.